# Understanding the output of Yolo v5

Tags: image-classification, object-detection, yolo

The label output file of the yolo v5 model is something like this:

```
0 0.0917969 0.907639 0.172656 0.170833 0.475255
1 0.387109 0.15 0.127344 0.291667 0.822308
0 0.115625 0.539583 0.195312 0.354167 0.828012
0 0.906641 0.473611 0.177344 0.35 0.829128
0 0.198047 0.283333 0.167969 0.322222 0.846307
0 0.796484 0.294444 0.160156 0.316667 0.866312
0 0.642187 0.179167 0.123438 0.272222 0.88274
```

- This text file is one of the results for the labels from detect.py. I
  know for sure that the 1st column is related to the class. As there
  are no headings in the text file, how can I know which these other
  columns are relating to. Values being normalized, it is difficult to
  understand which columns are for xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, confidence
  respectively.
- Is there any method that can be used in the detect.py to exclude the confidence column from this annotations text file.
- Also, I am little confused here because yolov5 accepts (xcentre, y
  centre, width, height) as input values of bounding boxes but, I guess, this output is in the form of (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax). Does yolov5 automatically makes this change.

Comment: the output is cx cy width height score.

Answer (score 0):

--save-conf argument in detect.py command is the solution.

Comment: Please Explain in more details